# Shell input/output redirection

Tags: c, shell, io, arguments, io-redirection

I am stuck with this method where it scans argv for any use of < or > which indicate input or output redirection
//command [arguments] [< infile] [> oufile]

I am implementing the redirect method that opens a file to read/write from it.
any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
void do_redirect(char **argv)
{
    int i;


    for(i=0; argv[i]; i++)
    {
            if (!strcmp(argv[i],"<")) {


                   int fp1 = open(argv[i+1] , O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0);                                             
                   dup2(fp1, STDIN_FILENO);
                   argv[i]=NULL; 
                   close(fp1);
            }
            else if (!strcmp(argv[i],">")) {

                    int fp2 = open(argv[i+1] , O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0); 
                    dup2(fp2, STDOUT_FILENO);
                    argv[i]=NULL;
                    close(fp2);
            }
       }

 }
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to implement that? I am kind of stuck, if you can point out what's wrong and needs to be fixed.

Comment: If you're not programming a shell you don't need it. If you are and asking how to implement io redirection, well it is way too broad a question for this website

Comment: yes I am doing a tiny shell lab and needto implement io redirection

Comment: refer to source codes of other shells

Comment: You will probably never get `<` or `>` in your command line because the shell already handles them and does not provide them to your program. You need to read a full command line from stdin or any stream on your won while your program is running and parse all the tokens on a line.

Comment: @Gerhardh please don't comment if you don't know what you're talking about. thanks

Comment: If you had provided a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it would be possible to see whether you know what you are talking about. We can only guess if you put that function in proper context. You don't show how you call that function. And you forgot to include the mandatory input, expected output and received output of your function.